# Can't center nav bar elements with text-align:center; nor margin: 0 auto;

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following nav bar from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_responsive_navbar_dropdown.asp
:

```js
function navBarFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
```

```css
.topnav {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
}


/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */
.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
.topnav .icon {
    display: none;
}

/* Dropdown container - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the dropdown button to fit inside the topnav */
    .dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 17px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}

    /* Style the dropdown content (hidden by default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

    /* Style the links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

    /* Add a dark background on topnav links and the dropdown button on hover */
.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}

/* Add a grey background to dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu when the user moves the mouse over the dropdown button */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width:850px) {
.topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
    }
.topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    }

.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
.topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
.topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
.topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
.topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset = "utf-8" />
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="/home" class="active">Home</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="/dhcpIP">DHCP IP</a>
            <a href="/staticIP">Static IP</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="/files">Import/Export Data</a>
    <a href="/radar">Radar Settings</a>
    <a href="/update">Update</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="navBarFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

These align to the left, because of the `float: left;`.

I have tried to eliminate the `float: left;`, change from `display: block;` to `display: inline-block;` and add `width` and `margin: 0 auto;` to `.topnav`. This will vertically misalign the dropdown button, center the nav bar but not the elements inside.

Comment: If you set the dropdown's overflow to initial or visible then the elements would align.. Although removing the `float: left;` would leave a space in between the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the topnav flex and then add a container for the nav elements and thus you can center the content inside. For example:

```js
function navBarFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
```

```css
.topnav {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
}


/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */
.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
.topnav .icon {
    display: none;
}

/* Dropdown container - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the dropdown button to fit inside the topnav */
    .dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 17px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}

    /* Style the dropdown content (hidden by default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

    /* Style the links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

    /* Add a dark background on topnav links and the dropdown button on hover */
.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}

/* Add a grey background to dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu when the user moves the mouse over the dropdown button */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width:850px) {
.topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
    }
.topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    }

.topnav.responsive {position: relative; flex-direction: column;}
.topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
.topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
.topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
.topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
}

.nav-elements {
flex-grow: 1;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset = "utf-8" />
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
<div class="nav-elements">
    <a href="/home" class="active">Home</a>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="/dhcpIP">DHCP IP</a>
            <a href="/staticIP">Static IP</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="/files">Import/Export Data</a>
    <a href="/radar">Radar Settings</a>
    <a href="/update">Update</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="navBarFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great. It works. Also, you don't need to add `display: flex;` to `.topnav`. It's enough to add it to the second container.